# Add & Remove TextView programmatically in Android

Tags: android, textview

I Successfully added TextView programmatically ... But My problem is ,how to delete TextView By programmatically ... Here is my Code 

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.textviewdemo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
<br>
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private TextView addTv;
    private EditText edt;
    private Button add, delete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int no = Integer.parseInt(edt.getText().toString());
                for (int i = 1; i <= no; i++) {
                    addTv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                    addTv.setText("TextView " + i);
                    addTv.setId(i);
                    ll.addView(addTv);
                }
            }
        });
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int no1 = Integer.parseInt(edt.getText().toString());
                for (int i = 1; i <= no1; i++) {
                    ll.removeView(addTv);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I click on Delete Button It only delete last TextView Only..
What Should I Do?

Answer (score 1):

Store all your TextViews in an array and do what you want. Now `addTv` is the last created TextView. Besides if you click delete before add you will get NullPointerException.

Also see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeViewAt(int) and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeViewsInLayout(int,%20int)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i<ll.getChildrenCount(); i++){
    if(ll.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView){
        ll.removeView(ll.getChildAt(i));
    } 
}
```

This will find all children of ll and remove them if they are instances of TextView